# How to do random ordering in MySQL. Should I use random() or uuid()

Tags: mysql

I want to get randomized results for a query. I read that using `RAND()` is quite slower. Can I use `order by uuid_short()` ? Will that be better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uuid_short()` is about two times slower than `rand()`, so no, you should **not** use `uuid_short()` instead of `rand()`.

```
mysql> select benchmark(100000000, rand());
1 row in set (3.25 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(100000000, uuid_short());
1 row in set (6.04 sec)
```

Comment: Is there a better way than random().. ?

Comment: I don't think there would be any _other_ random number generator in MySQL that would be _faster_ than `rand()`.

Comment: on my environment I got this output ( which is like rand took 0.4 ms more ):<p>mysql> select benchmark(100000000, rand());
+------------------------------+
| benchmark(100000000, rand()) |
+------------------------------+
|                            0 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (3.68 sec)

<p>mysql> select benchmark(100000000, uuid_short());
+------------------------------------+
| benchmark(100000000, uuid_short()) |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  0 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (3.28 sec)